# Rack::MockRequest response of "deadlock; recursive locking"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

I'm attempting to call a MockRequest twice to check if a URL exists for an attached rack app. It works fine the first time, but every other request shows a "deadlock; recursive locking" response. The call will be onKeyUp to check if a username exists in our system, so any sort of delay won't work for us.

Are we missing a command to clear the thread after running the call or something?

Ruby 2.2, Rails 4.1.

```
> Boulder::Application.call(Rack::MockRequest.env_for('https://brandfolder.com/start'))[0]
Started GET "/start" for  at 2015-01-06 12:36:29 -0700
=> 200

> Boulder::Application.call(Rack::MockRequest.env_for('https://brandfolder.com/start'))[0]
ThreadError: deadlock; recursive locking from /Users/Paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:16:in 'lock'

> Boulder::Application.call(Rack::MockRequest.env_for('https://brandfolder.com/start'))[0]
Started GET "/start" for  at 2015-01-06 12:36:29 -0700
=> 200

> Boulder::Application.call(Rack::MockRequest.env_for('https://brandfolder.com/start'))[0]
ThreadError: deadlock; recursive locking from /Users/Paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:16:in 'lock'
```